# Case sensitive input value in textbox with validation form

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have script when I will input data from a textbox.

For example: In the textbox, we may input anything string excepting(admin, Admin, ADMIN, AdmiN).  I am using this script, but i think my script is so long

Can you show me other ways, regex possibly, to do this?

```
<?php
$nama=$_POST['name'];
$pesan=$_POST['pesan'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if($nama== ("admin") || $nama==("Admin") || $nama==("AdmiN") || $nama=("ADMIN"))
      {
    echo "Masukkan nama yang lain";
        }else{
    $sql="insert into table1(nama,pesan)values('$nama','$pesan')";
    $result_sql=mysql_query($sql);
    header('Location:index.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to lower case:

```
if (strtolower($nama) === 'admin')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
//make an array of your restricted words, all in lowercase
$restrictedWordsArr = array("admin"); //and more you want
//then check
if(in_array(strtolower($yourWordToCheck), $restrictedWordsArr)) {
   //restricted word
}
else {
   //valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex, simply: `strtolower($nama) == "admin"`